# Which of the following are valid keywords in Go for controlling a loop?

Tags: go, control-flow

I saw this question that for correct answer had 'for and range'.

But the **for** statement is the only available looping statement in Go,and the range keyword allows you to iterate over items of a list like an array or a map. For understanding it, you could translate the range keyword to *for each index of*.

```
//for loop
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    fmt.Println("Value of i is now:", i)
    }
}

 //range is used inside a for loop


a := [...]string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
for i := range a {
    fmt.Println("Array item", i, "is", a[i])
}
capitals := map[string] string {"France":"Paris", "Italy":"Rome",     "Japan":"Tokyo" }
for key := range capitals {
    fmt.Println("Map item: Capital of", key, "is", capitals[key])
    }

//range can also return two items, the index/key and the corresponding value 
for key2, val := range capitals {
    fmt.Println("Map item: Capital of", key2, "is", val)
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question? The range keyword can be used in conjunction with a for loop. More info [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range)

Comment: What exactly is your question? The syntax is spelled out in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements

Comment: The question was:Which of the following are valid keywords in Go for controlling a loop? the correct answers were for and range.And I know and searched again to make sure that the for statement is the only available looping statement in Go

Comment: Both of them are valid. The only loop function missing in go is the `while` or `do..while`.

Comment: if this is for graded coursework I think `for` alone should be an acceptable answer, since you cant use range without for

Comment: Yes,this was my thought too,since you can't use range without for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is about Different Forms of For Loop:
simple loop variants working sample:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()

    i := 0
    for ; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()

    for i := 0; i < 10; {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println()

    //2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
    for i := 1; ; i++ {
        if i&1 == 1 {
            continue
        }
        if i == 22 {
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()

    i = 0
    for {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
        i++
        if i == 10 {
            break
        }

    }
    fmt.Println()

    for i, j := 0, 0; i < 5 && j < 10; i, j = i+1, j+2 {
        fmt.Println(i, j)
    }
}
```

for array, slice,string, map, channel using range keyword:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ary := [5]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    for index, value := range ary {
        fmt.Print("ary[", index, "] =", value, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
    for index := range ary {
        fmt.Print("ary[", index, "] =", ary[index], " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
    for _, value := range ary {
        fmt.Print(value, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()

    slice := []int{20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}
    for index, value := range slice {
        fmt.Println("slice[", index, "] =", value)
    }
    fmt.Println()

    str := "Hello"
    for index, value := range str {
        fmt.Println("str[", index, "] =", value)
    }
    fmt.Println()

    mp := map[string]int{"One": 1, "Two": 2, "Three": 3}
    for key, value := range mp {
        fmt.Println("map[", key, "] =", value)
    }
    fmt.Println()

    ch := make(chan int, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Print(i, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

and Label for break Label and continue Label:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a, b := 1, 1
Loop1:
    for {
        b++
    Loop2:
        for {
            a++
            switch {
            case a == 2:
                fallthrough
            case a == 3:
                fmt.Println(3)
            case a == 4, a == 5:
                continue
            case a == 7:
                continue Loop1
            case a == 9:
                break Loop2
            case a == 10:
                break Loop1
            case a == 8:
                break
            default:
                fmt.Println(a, b)
            }
        }
    }
}
```